# Apache redirect to another subdirectory if not in correct one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've got a folder structure like this

```
public_html/
  test/
    right/
      file.json
    wrong/
      file.json
```

So for example example.com/test/right/file.json is a valid url.

What I'm trying to do is if they hit anything else inside test/ they'll get redirected to wrong/file.json

So for example

```
example.com/test/right/file.json -> .../right/file.json
example.com/test/blah/file.json -> .../wrong/file.json
example.com/test/whatever/file.json -> .../wrong/file.json
```

I tried something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!right).*)$ http://example.com/test/wrong/file.json
```

But I was just getting into a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably looking for [`ErrorDocument`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ErrorDocument):

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/test/wrong/file.json
```

To allow only `right/file.json`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!(right|wrong)/file\.json$) http://example.com/test/wrong/file.json
```